# CSS Vertical Navigation bar not full screen height on Safari

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following HTML/CSS code for a vertical navigation bar:

HTML:

```
<div class="side-menu">
  <h2>
    Brand
  </h2>
  <div class="menu-top">
    <div class="menu-item" style="background-color: red">
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item" style="background-color: yellow"> 
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item" style="background-color: orange">  
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item" style="background-color: purple"> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-bottom">
    <div class="menu-item" style="background-color: blue">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body,
.side-menu {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.side-menu {
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
  background-color: black;
  width: 115px;
}

.menu-top {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.menu-item {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/mehg8uL2/ (please ensure you are using the columns view).

On Chrome and Firefox it works fine. ie. the Blue dot is at the bottom of the vertical navigation bar:

[image: Navbar on Chrome or Firefox]

But on Safari, it is not:

[image: Navbar on Safari]

As you can see, the blue circle is cut. Any idea how to make it cross browser?

Note: my actual navigation is dynamically generated so I don't know how many items are actually in the menu-bottom section.

Comment: Judging from the amount of how much of the blue circle is cut, maybe it has something to do with the h2? What happens, if you remove the h2 element?

Comment: Same thing without the h2. Weird thing is that Safari is not consistent with this. Sometimes it works ok and sometimes not. On multiple devices.

Comment: Please add an [example]. As the code sits, the issues cannot be replicated.